# Null reference exception on navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception

Can anybody suggest the cause of the following problem? My code is breaking on the line

```
integerList.Integers.Add(integer);
```

with the error message

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

IntegerList.Integers is null which I suspect is the cause but what is the solution? Do I have to set IntegerList.Integers values when I initialize the variable so it is never null?

**Models**

```
public class IntegerList
{
    public int IntegerListID { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    public long Performance { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Integer> Integers { get; set; }
}

public class Integer
{
    public int IntegerID { get; set; }
    public int IntegerValue { get; set; }
    public int IntegerListID { get; set; }
    public virtual IntegerList IntegerList { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class IntegerViewModel
{
    [UIHint("Integers")]
    public IntegerValueViewModel IntegerValues { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
}

public class IntegerValueViewModel
{
    public ICollection<int> IntegerValue { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IntegerViewModel integerViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var integerList = new IntegerList
            {
                Direction = integerViewModel.Direction
            };

            foreach (var item in integerViewModel.IntegerValues.IntegerValue)
            {
                var integer = new Integer { IntegerValue = item };
                integerList.Integers.Add(integer);
            }
```

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `Integers` property is not initialized and it is null. You were trying to call the `Add` method on a **null** thing which gave you an error

**Solution :** Initialize the property in the `IntegerList` class constructor

```
public class IntegerList
{
    public int IntegerListID { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    public long Performance { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Integer> Integers { get; set; }

    public IntegerList()
    {
      Integers =new List<Integer>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful of instantiating children objects as `new List<Integer>`. If you initialize the `Integers` child collection as a `new List<Integer>` in the constructor then when you want to do a `.Where` clause on the child property `Integers` you will get all the child `Integers` out of the Db for that parent record and then the `.Where` clause will be applied. If the child list is large then this affects performance dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
var integerList = new IntegerList
            {
                Direction = integerViewModel.Direction
            };
```

the associated Integers is not initialized, you can initialize it in IntegerList contsctructor. or do the following

```
var integerList = new IntegerList
                {
                    Direction = integerViewModel.Direction,
                    Integers=new List<Integer>()

                };
```